# Using a hub on port 80 for signal r

Tags: web-services, signalr, polling

I at the moment I am polling a web service from my c# desktop winform app to retrieve messages as and when they come in.  Instead of polling I thought maybe it would be better to receive a 'push' notification?  this lead me to the SignalR framework. As I understand you have to create a hub on the server. But, can i use port 80 or will I get an error stating that the port is is use by iis?  If so, is there an alternative to what I can do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two processes can not bind to the same port. If you have IIS running on port 80, you'll have to either proxy the other software through IIS or run it on a different port.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying,  That was what I thought as well.  So, as I have open up a port on the server to accommodate a hub then I will have to allow the same port on my desktop app to pass through any firewalls which is a slight pain :(

Comment: Not really. Firewalls usually need an exception for incoming connections, not for outgoing ones (Reasoning being that connections from the inside are benign). Your desktop application should be perfectly fine to connect to the server on the port.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  But if I am doing a 2 -way communication this would be an issue.  I should have mentioned that in my original post.  Thanks for ur feedback though

Comment: Depends on how you do your two-way. TCP, by nature, is two-way, and can be kept open for a long time. As long as the connection is established from the inside, it will be open to the outside and the server can send to it. On client side, you'll just `listen` on the socket. This will block the current thread until an interrupt occurs, and data arrives.

Comment: "port-sharing" is often used to run multiple processes on same port. So if SignalR support port-sharing then it should be possible.